# Unable to print Turkish characters from Xamarin.Forms application to Zebra mobile printer using CPCL

Tags: xamarin.forms, printing, bluetooth, zebra-printers

I am trying to print from a Xamarin.Forms application to Zebra ZQ220 mobile printer over bluetooth.

I installed Zebra.Printer.SDK version 2.15.2634 and i am able to print.

For Turkish character printing, i stored the font file SWISS721 in Zebra printer, and i am able to print Turkish characters via  Zebra Setup Utilities / Open Communication With Printer / Direct Communication using my CPCL code, which is below.

```
! 0 200 200 500 1
PCX 0 1 !<NRPLOGO.PCX
T SWF12.CPF 0 125 180  şŞ iİ üÜ ğĞ öÖ çÇ
T SWF08.CPF 0 1 225 Tarih : 01.01.2022     Makbuz No : NTQ4NzIzNTM=
PRINT
```

In Xamarin.Forms application, according to Zebra documentation, i created a string to store CPCL like below:

```
private const string RealTestLabelCpclSwiss = "! 0 200 200 500 1\r\n"
+ "PCX 0 1 !<NRPLOGO.PCX\r\n"
+ "T SWF12.CPF 0 125 180  şŞ iİ üÜ ğĞ öÖ çÇ\r\n"
+ "T SWF08.CPF 0 1 225 Tarih : 01.01.2022     Makbuz No : NTQ4NzIzNTM=\r\n"
+ "PRINT\r\n";
```

To send this string to printer, this needs to be converted to a byte array, and Zebra documentation uses UTF8 encoding like below :

```
return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RealTestLabelCpclSwiss);
```

I can print to printer but Turkish characters like şŞ İ Ğ are not printed correctly.

I assume this is an encoding issue, and i need to use maybe a different encoding, tried the encodings below:

```
return Encoding.Default.GetBytes(RealTestLabelCpclSwiss);

return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RealTestLabelCpclSwiss);

Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
return Encoding.GetEncoding(1254).GetBytes(RealTestLabelCpclSwiss);

return Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9").GetBytes(RealTestLabelCpclSwiss);
```

But still i can't print Turkish characters with Xamarin.Forms.

My test device is an iPhone and i also checked the west checkbox in iOS project properties / iOS Build / Internationalization.

How can i correct this encoding issue with Xamarin.Forms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I used

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9")
```

instead of

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9")
```

and i am able to print Turkish characters.

I didn't know this encoding name is case sensitive.